# GoBack to previous action in MSFlow

Tags: power-automate, ms-flow

I have a requirement where I'm designing a workflow on SharePoint online using MS Flow(power Automate).
I have multiple approvals in place but my objective is to go back to the previous approver if the task has been referred back. How can I achieve the same.

Any help on it would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is going back to previous steps is not supported and some [investigation](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/How-to-go-back-to-a-previous-step-in-Flow-or-manage-a-rejection/td-p/104257) seems to back this up.

What may help is to rethink the design of the flow. Instead of going back a step you could do the following:

1. Add a condition after the approval in question to check the response
2. If rejected, place a new approval request in the rejected condition and proceed from there as required.

The issue you may have is if you are expecting a continuous loop of rejections that require a lot of back and forth. In this case you could potentially use a Do Until loop that has both the approvals but checks against the second approval to complete the loop.

[image]

**UPDATE**

In the case of where you have more than two approvals a Switch statement can be used with a counter variable to indicate which stage of the approvals you are up to.

Start the counter at 1, have case statements for each approval step and as the outcome of each approval occurs use a condition statement to either set the variable to the next case statement or to the previous case statement depending.

The outcome of to Do Until will need to be changed to be the final approval result.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have 5 sequential approvals where I want at any stage it can be referred back to the previous one. With two, I can use until what you have suggested but how to do it for 4 or 5 approvals because if from the last approval it is referred back it will start from again which is not required my case

Comment: In the case of 3+ approvals we could probably add in a switch statement. Have a variable that is set at "1" before the do until. Have each sequential approval under a case of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and then have the outcome of each approval either move the variable up or down. I will see if I can mock this up and add it to the post.